# pygame trying to draw shrinking rects with random size & shrink rates but they flicker

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have made a class called "Particle" and these particles are basically just rectangles that shrink, move and get destroyed when they are too small

my **init** method has 5 optional arguments that if left at None will be assigned a random value

the particles are drawn using pygame.draw.rect
when the "size" and the "sizeDecay" argument are randomised, the particles flicker when moving and I don't know why because literally the only difference is that there is random starting value (the decrease is linear)

here is the code I think could be relevant :
init method

```
    RSizeR = [50, 100] # short for RandomSizeRange
    RSizeDecayR = [10, 30] # short for RandomSizeDecayRange (NOTE : this value is divided by 10)
    RSpeedR = [15, 50] # short for RandomSpeedRange (NOTE : this value is divided by 10)

    # shape = "s" for square or "c" for circle
    def __init__(self, startpos, shape, colour = None, size = None, sizeDecay = None, angle = None, speed = None):

        self.pos = [int(startpos[0]), int(startpos[1])]
        self.shape = shape

        if colour == None: self.colour = tuple(random.randint(0, 255) for i in range(3))
        else: self.colour = colour

        if size == None: self.size = random.randint(Particle.RSizeR[0], Particle.RSizeR[1])
        else: self.size = size

        if sizeDecay == None: self.sizeDecay = random.randint(Particle.RSizeDecayR[0], Particle.RSizeDecayR[1])
        else: self.sizeDecay = sizeDecay

        if angle == None: self.angle = random.randint(0, 360)
        else: self.angle = angle

        if speed == None: self.speed = random.randint(Particle.RSpeedR[0], Particle.RSpeedR[1])
        else: self.speed = speed


        self.xspeed = sin(self.angle) * self.speed
        self.yspeed = cos(self.angle) * self.speed

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.size, self.size)
```

update method (the True being returned tells the program to delete that particle)

```
    def update(self):

        self.pos[0] += self.xspeed / 10
        self.pos[1] += self.yspeed / 10

        self.size -= self.sizeDecay / 10

        if self.size <= 0:
            return True

        self.rect.width = int(self.size)
        self.rect.height = int(self.size)

        self.rect.center = (int(self.pos[0]), int(self.pos[1]))

        return False
```

draw method

```
    def draw(self):
        if self.shape == "s":
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, self.rect)
        elif self.shape == "c":
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, self.rect.center, int(self.size/2))
```

I have tried defining the random values outside of the class and passing those into the init method but the problem still occurred

my best guess is that calculating 2 extra random numbers is slowing the program somehow

**UPDATE**

the code I am using for updating the screen is in a while loop and looks like this

```
gameState = "running"

while gameState != "exit":

    # catching events here

    # rest of code here


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

and I am defining my window like so :

```
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60
SCREENSIZE = SCREENX, SCREENY = 800, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)
```

additionally, this is the code I am using to update and draw the particles to the screen (it lies inside of the particle class)

```
    @classmethod
    def UpAndDrawAll(cls):

        for index, par in enumerate(cls.Particles):
            delete = par.update()
            if delete:
                del cls.Particles[index]
            else:
                par.draw()
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have noticed that the random speed also has a very minor performance decrease and that the problem is caused by using randomly generated values - and not by generating the random numbers (still haven't solved the problem)

I have also noticed that some particles flicker more often that others and some do not even flicker

Comment: How is your code updating the screen?  What sort of frame-rate control are you using?  When is the display being `flip()`ed?  Is your Surface double-buffered? The flickering is probably caused by bad animation practices, and absolutely not the random numbers.

Comment: @Kingsley correct me if I am wrong, but I not sure if the problem is due to bad animation practices, because I am using the exact same code to animate the particles regardless of whether the size and sizeDecay arguments are randomised or not, and there is no flickering unless those 2 arguments are randomised

Comment: It doesn't make sense that extra computation time caused by a couple randint calls would cause this issue. Extra compute might slow things down, but slowness will not cause flicker. Erratic speed could make things jerky but not flicker. Also, looking at the code the random calls are in the __init__() which gets called only when creating a new Particle which presumably does not happen every pass, which would also argue against it being the cause of the flicker.

Comment: Lastly, though randint calls are not fast, they are also not so slow that a couple extra would cause that much of a performance hit. Your only talking about a couple microseconds per call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
The problem is that when particles were getting deleted (when they got too small) the draw() method was not being called on some particles

I found this out by making the particles invisible when they go too small instead of deleting them, this caused absolutely no flickering

I have replaced the UpdateAll() mehtod with this :

```
    @classmethod
    def UpAndDrawAll(cls):
        dellist = []

        for ind, par in enumerate(cls.Particles):
            delete = par.update()
            if delete:
                dellist.append(ind)
            else:
                par.draw()

        offset = 0
        for delind in dellist:
            del cls.Particles[ delind+offset ]
            offset -= 1
```

I'll leave this question up just in case someone else has a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't enough here to answer you.

However flicker is often caused by calling pygame.display.update or pygame.display.flip more than once per game loop. Make sure that you blit all the display changes required and only after all the position updates and blitting are completed, you call pygame.display.update or pygame.display.flip (but not both) at the end of the loop.